# Backscattering Overview and RFID

Tags: rf, rfid, passive-components

I'm having trouble understanding how RFID works on the technical side. I know an RF signal is sent to an antenna, modulated, and then backscattered back to the RFID reader.
For example,
Does this ON-OFF Keying system work?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqNdaj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My logic is as follows:
Then antenna receives the RF Signal.

The signal is absorbed through ground when the transistor is on and "acting" like a closed switch. This represents a zero.

When the transistor is off, it acts like an open circuit and reflects the RF Signal back to the antenna and the antenna radiates back to the reader. This represents a one.

What I see wrong with this is that the antenna cannot simultaneously transmit and receive the RF signal, or at least to my knowledge it can't.

Another example is this google image I found. How does the antenna receive, modulate, and send back a signal simultaneously. Are there two antennas that are "lumped" as one antenna?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these kinds of systems, "antenna" is a bit of a misnomer:

instead, consider the two coils of the reader and the tag as primary and secondary windings of a transformer. A simple measurement on how much power can be pushed through the transformer allows the reader to determine the "short-circuit-ness" of the tag side, to stay within your picture.

Comment: Is this because RFID usually operates in the near field? Is it feasible to have far-field backscattering system? I'm tasked to design one for a senior project and have an antenna I want to use, but I'm lacking in my EM modeling skills.

Comment: Wouldn't call it backscatter, but passive RFID system. These exist.

Comment: If you look at RFID operating at UHF band frequencies, then antenna is not a misnomer, they are actually antennas, we're talking 868/915 MHz, you don't use coils for those and communication distances can go up to 10 meters, so we're talking about far-field communication. And the principle is still the same, it's backscatter, the tag modulates an incoming signal being transmitted by the reader.